# Multiple marker on google map not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, google-map

Vf Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Hotel__c" extensions="HotelList" sidebar="false">
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {


    alert('Start of jQuery');
      HotelList.getHotelList(function(result,event){
        DemoLocationData = result;
        initialize()


    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (var i=0, l=DemoLocationData.length; i<l; i++){
                // the for..in statement should be use with caution, and its not intented to be used with an array. You should a for loop instead! 

                var p = DemoLocationData[i];
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.Location__latitude__s, p.Location__longitude__s);
                bounds.extend(latlng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                    position: latlng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: image,
                    title: p.Name
                });
        }

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }

    });
  </script>
</head>  
<body> 
    <apex:form>
        <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
    </apex:form>
</body>

</apex:page>
```

Controller Class is

```
public with sharing class HotelList {
    private ApexPages.StandardController controller;

      public HotelList(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;

      }
     // {!Hotel__c.Location__latitude__s},{!Hotel__c.Location__longitude__s})
     @RemoteAction
     public static list<Hotel__c> getHotelList(){
        list<Hotel__c> hotelDisplay =[SELECT Id, Name, Location__latitude__s, Location__longitude__s FROM Hotel__c];
        System.debug('List of Hotels returned>>>>'+  hotelDisplay );
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Location__latitude__s, Location__longitude__s FROM Hotel__c];
     }

}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add console log as well

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list